# How to set seed value of kernel initializer (glorot_uniform) in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, kernel, initializer, seed

I'd like to set seed value of glorot_uniform kernel initializer in Keras.

```python
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform(seed=0)'))
```

When I use above code, error message is below.

```python
ValueError: Unknown initializer: glorot_uniform(seed=0)
```

If I remove "(seed=0)" like as below

```python
 model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
```

It works well without setting a seed value.

How can I set a seed value?

Answer (score 9):

Keras can use strings and functions as arguments for initilizers. The strings just use the default options for initializers. 
Try this line of code for your FC layer:

```python
from keras import initializers
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0)))
```

Here you have the documentation for the initializers:
https://keras.io/initializers